# Getting rid of pre-compiled headers

Tags: gcc, precompiled-headers

OK, I have old Metrowerks code for Mac and Windows where the previous developer used pre-compiled headers for every project that this code base builds.

How does one get rid of Pre-compiled headers, conceptually?

do you take the contents of a .pch and move them to a core.h and include that in all of your classes .h files?

I want to move to building with CMAKE and although there are hacks to make pre-compiled headers work, I think that it would be best to remove dependencies to them.

Some may say things about compile speed, but I am not in a race, I have fast equipment already, I am more interested in how to get away from pre-compiled headers.

Comment: Wow, never had any reason to move **away** from precompiled headers. Weird.

Comment: @Frank - what about the fact that compilers deal with this differently and lack of portability? Or maybe subtle bugs? There are many threads here that deal with the issues of using them. I ask how to rid myself of them.....

Answer (score 1):

> How does one get rid of Pre-compiled headers, conceptually?

Precompiled headers are an optimization.  Conceptually you get rid of the precompiled headers by simply using the regular headers instead.

> do you take the contents of a .pch and move them to a core.h and include that in all of your classes .h files?

I know programmers who do this.  Personally I prefer to know which functions I'm using and where they came from, so I make sure each file `#include`s all the headers needed to compile that file (and only the headers needed to compile that file).  Then again, this does require constantly checking if a header is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Been there... in a C++ project where a central header was included by absolutely *every* translation unit, and in turn included almost every Boost header there is. Nice on the platforms where PCH's are supported, but we're compiling on some where they aren't, and they took *ages*. (As would your `core.h` approach. Don't do that, especially not with C++.)

So, here goes:

- grep for all inclusions of the PCH, and toss 'em (or, more gently, comment them out).
- for each translation unit, try to build, and add missing includes until you no longer get compiler errors.

Yep, that's the brute force approach. Unfortunately I know no better.